# Conditional Screen Rendering - How to hide origin screen tabBar and Header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

What i'm trying to achieve from the Orders Screen is: If the user is not logged in he is directed to another screen. Which is also part of the stack. The transition is well but the header of origin screen (which in this case is orders.js) doesnt change

Orders.js

```
    class Orders extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: <TextHeader title={I18n.t('tabsLang.orders')} />,
                headerTitleStyle: header.title,
                headerLeft: <View />,
                headerRight: <View />,
            };
        };

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                orders: true,
                isLoggedIn: false,
            };
        }

        render() {
            if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
                if (!this.state.orders) {
                    //Orders
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                            <OrderItem />
                        </View>
                    );
                } else {
                    //No Orders Screen
                    return <NoOrders />;
                }
            } else {
                return <UserSplash/>;
}
        }
    }

    export default Orders;
```

UserSplash.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            header: null,
        };
    };



    render() {...
    }
}
```

[image: image showing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I need to point out.

## 1. Double Header confusion

```
<Order>
    Static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: Something
    }
    render(){
        if(state.isLoggedIn){
            <View>
                ... Show orders or not
            </View>
        } else {
            <UserSplash>
                Static navigationOptions = {
                    header: null
                }
            </UserSplash>
        }
    }
</Order>
```

if you look at this, when you disable the header of the UserSplash, you are literally disabling the doubleheaders last one. If you don't disable it, you will see 2 headers on top of the view.

## 2. NavigationOptions

When you are setting the

> navigationOptions

you are declaring it as **Static** if you are realized that. So it is not possible to change the parameters. I suggest you separate the UserSplash from the Order.js and just Navigate with your navigation.

Hope it helps. Good luck!